# creating a link between structures with void pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, tree

I want to create a linkedlist/tree type of structure with links between nodes being `void*`.

```
struct node1{
  void* left;
  void* right;
}

struct node2{
 void* next; 
 int data;
}

int main(){

 struct node1* node1=malloc(sizeof(struct node1));
 struct node2* node2=malloc(sizeof(struct node2));
 node2->data=5;
 node1->left=*(struct node2*)node2);
 node1=node1->left

 }
```

I want to acces `node2`'s data using `node1` and its links, but the above code doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: I see problems with `*(struct node2*)node2`. First of all you don't need the cast, since `node2` already is of the type `struct node2 *`. Secondly, you dereference the pointer to get the actual structure itself.

Comment: Furthermore `node1=node1->left` will make you lose the original `node1` pointer, leading to a memory leak. Not to mention that `node1->left` is supposed to point to a `node2` structure, which mixes up the types a lot. Why can't you use the proper types? Why do you think you need to use `void *`? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: The problem is that you did not turn warnings of your compiler on. It would have told you everything you needed to know.

Comment: it is an assignment work ı have to use void* to bind the structs together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
 node1->left=*(struct node2*)node2);
```

Contains a syntax error and an unneeded cast. It also dereferences the value of `node2`, which makes it wrong.

This:

```
 node1=node1->left;
```

Is also *wrong*. You cannot assign a different type of pointer to `node1`. Of course, `node1->left` is `void*` so this is actually a valid assignment per se, but it will result in `node2` being interpreted as of type `struct node1*`, which is wrong.

The correct code, if I correctly understood what you want to do, would be:

```
int main(void) {
    struct node1* node1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node1));
    struct node2* node2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node2));

    node2->data = 5;
    node1->left= node2;

    // Access node2->data from node1:
    ((struct node2*)node1->left)->data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thx for the hint, as it turns out it was a typo in the question.